# Touch gestures not working on auto scroll iOS

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

i am trying to achieve auto scroll. I am done with the auto scroll part but now touch gestures are not working. Touch gestures include user interaction to scroll left and right of his own and go to detail controller on tapping any item etc

here is my code

```
var sponsorScroll: UIScrollView!
var xOffSet: CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
}

@objc func timerAction() {
        print(1)
        self.xOffSet += 50;
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(2)
            if self.sponsorScroll.contentSize.width < (self.sponsorScroll.contentOffset.x + UIScreen.main.bounds.width) {
                self.xOffSet = 0
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
                    print(4)
                    self.sponsorScroll.contentOffset.x = self.xOffSet
                }, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
                    print(3)
                    self.sponsorScroll.contentOffset.x = self.xOffSet
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can allow scroll view drag by setting your animate options to: `[UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear, UIView.AnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction]`. You'll have some additional work to do, but that should get you started.

Comment: thanks alot @DonMag. That's all what was needed to do. Working like a charm!!